Is this confirmation modal too intrusive for deleting custom fields?
I have a form where the user can add custom fields to products. If a folder requires a custom field, and the product is in that folder, then deleting that custom field will trigger a confirmation modal. It will tell the user that the product will be removed from the folder, because it no longer satisfies the requirement of the folder.

This means that the user will see that popup quite often. And let's say that folder requires five custom fields and the product has all of them...the user is going to see that confirmation modal five times.
Do you think this is too intrusive for the user? If so, what alternative do you suggest?

Alternatively, you can make the custom field to be immediately deleted after user action and show a feedback alert popup with a button labeled "Undo" to prevent mistakes.
BUT if you see it's a very important information, and the user will be very mad at your product if they accidentally delete this field (since we tend to not read everything on screen), don't be afraid of adding a little friction. If that's the case, also think about microcopy of those buttons.

Agreed with the above that allowing the user to undo that action might avoid the need for the big blockade of a confirmation dialog. But that said, you want to make sure to confirm any non-reversible (especially destructive) action, so the confirmation dialog is not out of place in a world without undo.
As far as the potential frequency of that dialog, might you allow a user to select multiple custom fields and then batch-delete them so they DON'T need to see it five times? A checkbox to the left of each field row would allow the selections, and then they could all be deleted either by triggering any one of the Delete controls - with an appropriate confirmation message like "You are about to delete five items, you sure?" - or a newly exposed "Delete all selected" type control that appears at the top of the list as soon as more than one item is selected (a common pattern).
Either option is going to require some development time. On the whole if you do not commonly have an Undo pattern in the UI I would suggest adding multi-select with batch controls for bulk deletion, but that's up to you.
